# Button to drop pin in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, annotations, mkmapview

I want to have a button that says "WARN" and when the user pushes the button a pin will drop down on his location. But I can't figure out how to do that. It must be possible to halve multiple pins at the map, so the last annotation dropped doesn't diseppear when a new user presses the "WARN" button. Can somebody help me with this code please?

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you some code to ad to your post?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you start off with something a bit easier, and take it from there. We won't write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out this example from Apple's documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746